# How can I reference PrimeNG AutoCompleteModule in dotnet angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, asp.net-core, primeng

I have been writing an application that requires auto-complete.I started by installing some available templates from the dotnet command line tool followed by choosing a director and installing the angular template.

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
dotnet new angular
```

I came across PrimeNg which seems to fit my needs for my auto-completion. After this, I tried to install PrimeNg from npm as follows:

```
npm install primeng
```

This created a folder in the node_modules as expected.

Next, I followed the instructions on how to setup PrimeNg in the app.module.js folder.

```
import { AutoCompleteModule } from primeng/components/autocomplete/autocomplete';
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ AutoCompleteModule, ... ]
});
```

In my html file I put the following directive including the bound search method and results list.

```
<p-autoComplete formControlName="city" (completeMethod)="search($event)"  
    [suggestions]="results"></p-autoComplete>
```

The application doesn't work as soon as I add the import in the @NgModule. I get this error that I can't find much on google about.

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: element.querySelector is not a function
TypeError: element.querySelector is not a function**

Now, for the strange part. If I start the application without the import the application starts fine. Now, if I type in the import at run time and save the control renders as if it was working properly.

[image]

As soon as I refresh the browser the problem is back and I get the aforementioned exception again. All my trials have been fruitless. The funny thing is that as I was trying things the code started to work even after I refreshed the browser several times only to, shortly thereafter, completely stop working at all.

Answer (score 0):

**usually:** only adds, but for asp.net core is different

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

**For asp.net core:** copypaste in wwwroot the file resource of primeng, found in node_modules and add in _Layout.cshtml, so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/resources/primeng.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried, and it also works adding Index.cshtml, by structure, it would be better to put it in Index.cshtml